# get gmail user available status

Tags: java

I have email list for my gmail id...it got using XMPP...how can i get those user status availability in java...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)

```
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
      "talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
XMPPConnection conn = new XMPPConnection(config);
conn.connect();
conn.login("yourid@gmail.com", "password");
Roster roster = conn.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> set = roster.getEntries();
for (RosterEntry re: set) {
   System.out.println(">> " + re.getUser());            
   Presence pres = roster.getPresence(re.getUser());
   //This is the status. 
   System.out.println("\t> " + pres.getMode());
}
```

Use [`Prescence.getStatus()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Presence.html#setStatus(java.lang.String)) to get the message string

Comment: i used this code but it return unavailabke for all email address...
actually i have 3 online id